# Given 2 sets A $\subset$ B , is D\A $\supset$ D\B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given 2 sets A  $\subset$ B , is  D\A  $\supset$ D\B ? , if D is another set ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Hint: let $d\in D\setminus B$. Show that $d\in D\setminus A$.